# How can I share application elements between multiple applications in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I share Application Elements between applications in Oracle APEX not referending all the Elements in all applications.

Hi everyone. I have a “parent” application where I define an Application Element called `G_GLOBAL`. I want to reference this element in a “child” application. It's important to say that both applications are sharing their sessions. I've been seeing that if I reference the same Application Element with the same name in the child application, I can get the value correctly, buy I think it's a little bit tedious referencing all the application elements from the parent app in the child app. So my cuestion is, Is there a proper way to reference that element in a easier way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope, all components needs to exist in the application itself. You can't reference something in another application.

Comment: Then is there a proper way to reference massively all the global variables in another application?

Comment: As I stated in my first comment: You can't reference something in another application

Answer (score 0):

You can define Applications Items in the Shared Components with the Scope set to **Global**. [Like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97tlo.png).

If you create the same variable in any other app and have a shared session, the App Item points to the same value.